# How do I create a csv file in SSRS with a .txt extension in the file name?

Tags: csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-subscription

I have a report where I have added a data driven subscription that writes the report to a folder location on a daily schedule. The report is rendered as csv. the file name comes as MyReport1234.**csv**.

I need this to be Myreport1234.**txt**. How can I do this in SSRS?

I use SSRS 2008 R2 btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution for this:

1. Create a data driven subcscription
2. on Step 3, just write `SELECT 1` or if you're trying to generate a dynamic file you could embed the logic for this in your select statement and give it an alias like `SELECT 'Myreport1234.txt' as [FileName]`
3. on Step 4, either Specify a static file name, or get the value from the database using the column "FileName" which you created in the previous step.
4. set the **Render Format** to **CSV**
5. This is the important step >> **File Extension** must be set to **False**. This will stop the renderer from adding the default extension for the renderer of your choice. leaving whatever thats on the filename to appear as the file extension.